# Why am I getting this output from a C union with bitfields in my code?

Tags: c, data-structures, unions, bit-fields

Sorry for the non descriptive title - I wasn't sure how to pose this in one line.

I have a data structure, where I have two values: one 14-bit, one 10-bit. I want to be able to access them as bytes in a union. I have the following:

```
struct test
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            unsigned int a : 14;
            unsigned int b : 10;
        } fields;
        
        struct
        {
            unsigned char i0;
            unsigned char i1;
            unsigned char i2;
        } bytes;
    } id;
};
```

Now, when I assign 1 to the value at `bytes.i2`, I would expect the value at `values.b` to also assume the value 1. But the value in `values.b` is actually `bytes.i2` shifted left by 2 bits.

```
int main()
{
    struct test x;
    x.id.bytes.i2 = 1;
    printf("%d", x.id.fields.b); // OUTPUTS 4
    return 0;
}
```

I must be missing some basic principle here, any insight would be helpful!

Comment: Reading from a different union member than you last wrote to is undefined behavior.

Comment: In this case, the result depends on whether it's little-endian or big-endian.

Comment: Unlike `struct`, [union](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm) by definition has one memory block that is shared by all members.  The last one written to is the only one that should be read from.

Comment: Ok, that's good to know. I was using the union just as a way to cast memory values to different types.

Comment: @Barmar Is it necessarily UB?  C11 footnote 95: *"If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to
store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as  an  object  representation  in  the  new type  as  described  in  6.2.6  (a  process  sometimes  called  ‘‘type punning’’).  This might be a trap representation"*  This suggests it is valid as long as there is no trap representation.

Comment: @Barmar I thought that was the legal way to do type punning in C, and only undefined in C++ :S

Comment: @dbush OK, then it's implementation-dependent. The way that bit fields map onto integers isn't specified.

Comment: Given `x.id.bytes.i2 = 1;`, `x.id.bytes.i0` and `x.id.bytes.i1` have *indeterminate* values along with any padding in the `bytes` structure, and since there's no way to know without specifying the implementation which bits of each bit-field line up with each `char`-sized set of bytes, you can't expect any value given what you've posted so far.  In fact, if `int` is 4 bytes on your system, you really need to add `x.id.bytes.i3` to examine anywhere your bit-fields could be.

Answer (score 2):

In little endian, packed structs:

```
fields a              |b
bytes  i0      |i1    :  |i2
BITS   00000000|000000|00|10000000 i2 = 1; b = 4
BITS   00000000|000000|10|10000000 i1 = 64; b = 1
INDEX  01234567|890123|45|67890123
       0          1           2
```

As you can see b = 0b00000100 (4)

Answer (score 1):

The exact layout and ordering of bitfields in a struct is entirely up to the implementation.

On a little endian machine, the layout of the union most likely looks like this:

```
|a              |b   a          |b              |
|7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0|1 0 d c b a 9 8|a 9 8 7 6 5 4 3|
|      i0       |      i1       |       i2      |
-------------------------------------------------
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
-------------------------------------------------
```

In this layout, we can see that the 8 low order bits of `a` are in the first byte, then the 6 high order bits of `a` and the 2 low order bits of `b` in the second byte, followed by the high order 8 bits of `b` in the third byte.  This explains the result you're seeing.

Little endian machine will typically also have the *bits* in little endian format, so if you reverse the order of the bits in each byte above, reflecting the physical representation instead of the logical representation, you can see that the bits of each bitfield are contiguous.

Comment: You've mixed your endianness, resulting in a very confusing picture -- you have bytes left-to-right (little-endian) and bits right-to-left(big-endian)